# Multiply by 2 - Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, multiplication

The input takes numbers until a negative number is entered, every number before that is multiplied by 2 and the result is printed and formatted to the 2nd digit after the comma.
I've tried the following, however the loop just continues endlessly giving me only 1 result, how can I make it stop and multiply with the next input instead?

```
x = float(input())
while x > 0:
    result = x * 2
    if x < 0:
        print('Negative number!')
    print(f'Result: {result:.2f}')
```

Comment: Where you take input is before the loop, not inside it; so that only happens once.

Comment: You can put your input code inside the while loop.

Comment: `if x < 0:` will never be true, because you only go into the loop when `x > 0`

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure that a while loop should be used, instead of a for

Comment: For loops are better if you want to do something a predetermined amount of times. While loops are better if you want to do something until a condition is met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. Here's the fixed version:

```py
while True:
    x = float(input("Input: "))
    if x < 0:
        print('Negative number!')
        break
    else:
        result = x * 2
        print(f'Result: {result:.2f}')
```

"break" is needed to interrupt the while loop on the first bad result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I will surely take another look at the loop and fix my mistakes. I was not entirely sure how the entire thing should look like however this has shined some light.